# R - ggplot2: geom_text with fontsize scaled to window size

Tags: r, ggplot2, viewport, geom-text, r-grid

a function that I'm writing uses `ggplot2::geom_text()`. However, I need the fontsize to stay scaled to the window size, meaning: If the size of the window is decreased the fontsize has to decrease, too, and vice versa in case of increasing the window size. I did not find a solution online. Therefore, I'm trying to create a ggplot2 `GeomTextScaled` that works slightly different than `GeomText` does. Inspired by [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/08/creating-a-text-grob-that-automatically-adjusts-to-viewport-size/) I wrote the preliminary solution below. This is probably incredibly awkward to everybody who is familiar with `grid` and grobs etc.

```
# awkward temporary solution
# other fns. resizingGrobText, drawDetails.resizingTextGrob,
# preDrawDetails.resizingGrobText, postDrawDetails.resizingGrobText

#' @export
resizingTextGrob <- function(...){

  grid::grob(tg = grid::textGrob(...), cl = "resizingTextGrob")

}



# draw --------------------------------------------------------------------

drawDetails <- grid::drawDetails

#' @exportS3Method
drawDetails.resizingTextGrob <- function(x, recording = TRUE){

  grid::grid.draw(x$tg)

}



# pre ---------------------------------------------------------------------

preDrawDetails <- grid::preDrawDetails

#' @exportS3Method
preDrawDetails.resizingTextGrob <- function(x){

# awkward...
  size.x <-
    base::get(
      x = "temp_x.size.scale.bar.text.x_temp",
      envir = .GlobalEnv
    )

  h <- grid::convertHeight(unit(size.x, "snpc"), "mm", valueOnly=TRUE)

  fs <- scales::rescale(h, to=c(18, 7), from=c(120, 20))

  grid::pushViewport(viewport(gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = fs)))

}


# post --------------------------------------------------------------------

postDrawDetails <- grid::postDrawDetails

#' @exportS3Method
postDrawDetails.resizingTextGrob <- function(x){  grid::popViewport()}


# ggplot2 --------------------------------------------------------------------

#' @title GeomTextScaled
#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
GeomTextScaled <- ggplot2::ggproto(
  `_class` = "GeomTextScaled",
  `_inherit` = ggplot2::Geom,
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "label"),
  default_aes = aes(
    colour = "black", size = 3.88, angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,
    vjust = 0.5, alpha = NA, family = "", fontface = 1, lineheight = 1.2
  ),
  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord, parse = FALSE,
                        na.rm = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE) {

    lab <- data$label

    data <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)

    size.x <- data$size

# awkward...
    base::assign(
      x = "temp_x.size.scale.bar.text.x_temp",
      value = size.x,
      envir = .GlobalEnv
    )

    resizingTextGrob(
      label = lab,
      x = data$x,
      y = data$y,
      default.units = "native",
      rot = data$angle,
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = ggplot2::alpha(data$colour, data$alpha),
        fontfamily = data$family,
        fontface = data$fontface,
        lineheight = data$lineheight
      ),
      check.overlap = check_overlap
    )


  },

  draw_key = ggplot2::draw_key_text
)

#' @export
geom_text_scaled <- function(...,
                            mapping = ggplot2::aes(),
                            data = NULL,
                            stat = "identity",
                            position = "identity",
                            na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA,
                            inherit.aes = TRUE){

  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = GeomTextScaled,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    params = c(..., list(na.rm = na.rm)),
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    mapping = mapping
  )

}
```

This is an example that works...

```
# example -----------------------------------------------------------------
​
library(ggplot2)
​
ggplot() +
  geom_text_fixed(
    data = data.frame(x = 25, y = 25, label = "scaled_to_window"),
    mapping = aes(x = x, y= y, label = label),
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = data.frame(x = 75, y = 75, label = "stays the same"),
    mapping = aes(x = x, y= y, label = label),
    size = 5
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,100))
​
```

But it only works under two conditions that I'd like to have removed:

1. I can not "communicate" via the `size` argument with `preDrawDetails()` and have to assign a variable to the global environment every time I use it. I'd prefer not to do this but I don't know how to access the method for resizingGrobText().
2. I'm actually writing a package where I have to export everything. If I load the code below in the global environment everything works. If I only load the package via `devtools::load_all()` it does not.

How can I solve this?

If there is an easier solution than writing a whole new Geom that I just don't find with google I am happy to use it! I just need the text in this plot to remain scaled to the viewport size.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

....

Comment: This post actually starts with "Hello everybody, " But for whatever reason it is not printed and editting does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case it is just easier to make a `makeContent.my_class` method than all the three methods you wrote before. Below, we scale the fontsize such that is a fraction of the width of the panel.

```r
#' @export
resizingTextGrob <- function(...){
  grobTree(tg = textGrob(...), cl = "resizingTextGrob")
}

#' @export
#' @method makeContent resizingTextGrob
makeContent.resizingTextGrob <- function(x) {
  width <- convertWidth(unit(1, "npc"), "pt", valueOnly = TRUE)
  fontsize <-  x$children[[1]]$gp$fontsize
  fontsize <- if (is.null(fontsize)) 12 else fontsize
  x$children[[1]]$gp$fontsize <- fontsize * width / 100
  x
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem 2.) is solved! Thank you! But now the text size remains the same if I change the size of the viewport. As a clarification: With size of viewport I mean the window in which the plot is plotted. Maybe viewport is not the right name to refer to it. `dev.size()` gives me the dimensions of the window. If I use the mouse cursor to increase or decrease the window the values outputted by `dev.size()` decrease or increase accordingly. I need the text size to change, too. Sorry, if that was misleading.

Comment: The term 'viewport' has a specific meaning in grid and the viewport of any ggplot2 layers is the panel in which the data is plotted (which indeed adapts to the device window, barring axes, strips and whatnot).  The method in the answer adapts the text size to the width of the panel. If you want to include the height too you might want to use `"snpc"` instead of `"npc"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! using 'snpc' instead of 'npc' does the trick regarding problem 1)!! Now I again/still face problem 2). Am I running in any documentation pitfalls? I added `makeContent <- grid::makeContent` above your code, otherwise I get an error that objet makeContent can not be found in the namespace of my package. S3method(makeContent,resizingTextGrob) is the first entry in my NAMESPACE file. However, after installing the package I can not access packagename::makeContent.

Comment: I wouldn't re-assign `grid::makeContent()`. I would declare {grid} under the 'Imports' field of the DESCRIPTION file, then use `@importFrom grid makeContent` as a doc string, which roxygen2 then ports to your NAMESPACE file.

Comment: I don't know if I'm commenting this twice now but it worked. So thanks alot!!! (I had answered yesterday but it had not been saved as it seems.)